# Insomnia failing with Maximum call stack size exceeded when importing the swagger json

Tags: insomnia

I am having swagger ui for my application and when I try to import the same to insomnia rest client I am getting ***Maximum call stack size exceeded*** error.[Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewgeZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is still an open issue. You can track progress [here](https://github.com/Kong/insomnia/issues/1367).